# Subviews of UIScrollView not responding to touch following animation of Scroll View's height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I am making an application that has a UIScrollView that expands to a height of 280 and contracts to a height of 0 when dismissed. I used a scroll view because a regular view would not "hide" its subviews after the animation to a 0 height. Initially, before any animating of the Scroll View has occurred, the subviews respond as expected to touch, but after the view's height has been animated at all, all of the subviews stop responding to user touch. I've tried ensuring that the zPosition of all of the subviews is greater than any other view in the view controller, so that isn't the issue. It appears that all of the subviews' frames are within their superview's. Below is the link to a video of my issue:

[My Issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvFAYKh4fUI&feature=youtu.be)

Here is the code for what occurs when my "parametersButton" is pressed:

```
@IBAction func parametersButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {

        if self.parametersExpanded {

            //Close searchView, make shadowView transparent
            self.searchView.frame.size.height = 0
            self.parametersButton.frame = self.parametersButton.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -280)
            self.searchView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            self.shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0)
        } else {

            //Expand the searchView, darken shadowView
            self.searchView.frame.size.height = 280
            self.parametersButton.frame = self.parametersButton.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 280)
            self.searchView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 230/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1)
            self.shadowView.layer.zPosition = 990
            self.shadowView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.868)
        }
    }) { (bool) in
    }
}
```

Note that in my application, the searchView is originally dismissed, i.e. having a frame height of 0. For this demonstration, I've made it so that when the application loads for the first time, the view is expanded so I can demonstrate that the subviews respond before animation of their superView. Additionally, there is the shadowView that I use to darken the views behind it, but it is pretty clearly behind the searchView so that isn't the issue.

Comment: *"a regular view would not "hide" its subviews"* ... did you set `.clipsToBounds = true` on your "regular view"?

Comment: @DonMag let me replace the scroll view with a regular view, set clipsToBounds to true and get back to you

Comment: @DonMag changed the view to a UIView that has clipsToBounds equal to true and while the subviews now disappear, the problem persists that when the view is initially open, the subviews are responsive, but after closing and reopening, they no longer respond to touch.

Comment: If you comment-out all the `.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` lines, do the buttons respond to touch when closed/opened?

Comment: As a side note, I don't think the `.layer.zPosition` lines are doing what you think they're doing... that `.zPosition` property is related to the ***internal layer*** of the control, not to the "z-order" of the views / buttons / sliders / etc.

Comment: @DonMag those items having their .isUserInteractionEnabled set to false are behind the searchView, not subviews of it. This portion of the code can essentially be ignored. The subviews Of searchView actually aren’t changed at all in this function

Comment: That code just confuses the issue then... Strip your example down to *only* what you're trying to do. See: [mcve]

Comment: @DonMag noted & fixed

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing all of your code and layouts, there are too many unknowns to figure out what's going on. There is no reason for controls to stop responding, simply by changing the superView's height. I'd highly recommend, though, that you use constraints and auto-layout, which will greatly simplify your tasks and eliminate any explicit size calculations. Here is a simple demonstration: https://github.com/DonMag/ShowHidePanelView

Comment: @DonMag thanks Don but I’ve been using auto layout constraints. I appreciate your efforts though.

Comment: Hmmm? The code you show uses `self.searchView.frame.size.height =` and `self.parametersButton.frame =` ... both of which will be problematic if you're *also* using auto layout constraints on those elements.

Comment: @DonMag I constrained the subviews to each other and to the superview. I also constrained searchView’s height. When changing searchView’s I’m programmatically changing it’s frame instead of changing its height constraint. Are you suggesting I try adjusting it’s height constraint as opposed to its frame?

Comment: If you look at the example project I put up, you'll see that I used constraints *only*. Yes, changing a frame that contradicts a constraint will cause problems (maybe not immediately identifiable, but it will eventually). Plus, there must be something else your code is doing that's causing the controls to stop responding. As I mentioned earlier, follow [mcve] ... and see if you can post full code that actually shows the problem.

Comment: @DonMag as it turns out, it did have to do with the changing of constraints as opposed to changing the frame itself. I looked at your example and pretty much deconstructed/reconstructed the view and it works fine now. If you want to post an answer I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per OP comments...

The likely issue was due to explicitly changing the frame(s) of the view elements, which were set up with auto-layout constraints. Common issue, and can cause all sorts of odd errors / conditions.

Changing the animated view collapse / expand methods to changing constraint properties instead of explicit frame changes fixed the problem.